# Left fill variable with zeros in FORMATMESSAGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatmessage

Using SQL Server's FORMATMESSAGE command, I am printing status messages:

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('Run time #%2d: From %s to %s', @i, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @from_date, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @to_date, 101))
```

This gives me output like:

```
Run time # 8: From 03/21/2019 to 04/21/2019
Run time # 9: From 04/21/2019 to 05/21/2019
Run time #10: From 05/21/2019 to 06/21/2019
Run time #11: From 06/21/2019 to 07/21/2019
```

But how do I zero fill if the @i variable is less than 10. It gives me the two positions, but I can't figure out the character to left fill with zeros.

Comment: Try: `RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(@i), 2)`

Comment: How about format(@i,'00')

Comment: @dvo Nope, I want to do it within the format string. I don't even want to convert the dates, but I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `%0{# of digits}i` (`%02i`) like so:

```
Declare @i int = 2

PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('La La La: %02i', @i)

-- OUTPUT: 'La La La: 02'
```

Your string:

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('Run time #%02i: From %s to %s', @i, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @from_date, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @to_date, 101))
```

Comment: I was composing my answer as you were composing yours. Thanks!

Comment: @CountBoxer Nice solution. Glad you found something to work

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: it looks like [FormatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) supports more formatting options and you can easily specify as many leading 0's as you like:

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('Run time #%02d: From %s to %s', @i, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @from_date, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @to_date, 101))
```

Comment: I want to do it within the format string. Other languages like Java have this feature.

Comment: Plus one for the link. It would also be nice if you could directly insert a date without casting it to a string. Because I use octal and hex so much more than date!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how Java does it solved my problem.The first 0 is to zero fill and the second number is the number of columns to use.

```
Run time #%02d: From %s to %s
```

Returns:

```
Run time #08: From 03/21/2019 to 04/21/2019
Run time #09: From 04/21/2019 to 05/21/2019
Run time #10: From 05/21/2019 to 06/21/2019
Run time #11: From 06/21/2019 to 07/21/2019
```

Using:

```
Run time #%-4d: From %s to %s
```

left justifies in four columns. Cool!